# negative regex in package.json

Tags: regex, jestjs

In my package.json, I have a regex to process only the files that contain '.integration.'

The command is the following:

```
"test:integration": "jest .*\\.integration\\..*"
```

How can I select files that DON'T contain  '.integration.' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, an expression similar to,

```
^(?!.*\\.integration\\.).*$
```

might be somewhat close, not sure though.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dPEhpw/1/)

Comment: Many thanks. Actual command that works in package.json is : jest \"^(?!.*\\.integration\\.).*$\"